# Font Awesome icons not displaying despite local hosting and CORS fix

Tags: html, css, path, icons, font-awesome

I'm encountering an issue where Font Awesome icons are not displaying on my live web server despite hosting the Font Awesome files locally. I initially faced a CORS issue, which was resolved by local hosting. However, the icons are still not visible on the webpage. I am using Google Chrome as my browser. Also I have not inluded my link path because I have downloaded version 6.4.2 and it is extremely long
How I have linked it in my HTML file

```
<div class="sidebar">
        <header class="title"> x's habit tree</header>
  
        <ul>
   
   <li> <a href= "#"> <i class="fas fa-search">search </i> </a> </li>
```

I have confirmed that there are no console errors, and I have already checked the following:

The path to the Font Awesome CSS file is correct.
The Font Awesome CSS file is loading properly.
There are no errors in the console.
Despite all this, the icons are still not showing up. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it just that icon that isn’t showing or is it any that you try?

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome changed the syntax of their tags between version 5 and version 6. You are using a version 5 tag but linking to version 6, which won't work. You also need to put the “search” text outside the `<i>` tags, rather than inside.

Font Awesome 6

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
<p><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> search</p>
```

Font Awesome 5

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"/>
<p><i class="fas fa-search"></i> search</p>
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped the problem my mistake!